# Weird Mongodb issue with finding methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using Node.js I have some simple code which gets a db after connecting to my mongodb, and executes some simple methods.  But the console give error if I try to do a `var collection = db.getCollection('Profiles');`

Here is my code:

```
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

 var collection = db.getCollection('Profiles');


}
```

error shows

server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:522
          throw err
                ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getCollection'

Comment: Try  `var collection = db.collection('Profiles');` instead.

Comment: That works, but the documental clearly says I can use it: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/  Does that mean the doc is wrong?

Comment: No, the doc is not wrong; you are trying to use the mongo shell API on the node.js driver which is wrong, use the driver API [methods](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#collection) instead.